# Documentum -Dynamic- User Management

Tags: administration, user-management, documentum, profiles

In our organisation users are assigned group memberships according to the team(s) assignments. This leads to groups sets referred to as 'profiles' in our documentation.

My question is: How can an administrator, preferred non IT, assign users to a set of groups as efficient as possible?

Keep in mind, due to naming conventions group names are specific, but dynamic dependent on the current project(s).

Comment: no idea?... no response?

Comment: A non-IT person administering users efficiently?  Sounds like you will  need a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to give an admin or managers, create group privilege (user account setting) and let them manage who is in what groups.

Assuming your organisation is already using a user and group management system, then investigate if Documentum can sync user and group information. Depending on your Documentum version, it can sync to user and group information from LDAP or Active Directory system.